# NPM "deprecated Babel preset" warnings, multiple "gyp ERR!"'s in console installing with NPM, unable to upgrade Babel

Tags: npm, npm-install, babeljs, node-gyp

When trying to install packages via NPM I first run into warnings telling me to upgrade Babel:

> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
>
> npm WARN @babel/preset-env@7.1.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I have tried following various steps to upgrade including

> npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

But when I run this command I get various npmERR! and gypERR! error messages.

```html
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-28T14_37_55_648Z-debug.log
```

If anyone could shed some light on the cause of these errors it would be appreciated. The full debug log is too long for me to paste here.

Comment: Looks like your Babel version is too old, try updating it to version 6 or 7 (latest)

Comment: Correct, but as I stated in the post, I have tried updating but get multiple gyp and npm errors when I run

Comment: Hmm, you stated that you tried to install babel-preset-env, I think you have to update Babel itself first.

Comment: I have also tried ">npm i babel-install" and ">npx babel-upgrade --write".
But the same errors persist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly sure if this will fix your specific problem, but I ran into something similar. I was trying to install `babel` and the `babel preset` so that I could compile `ES6` code into `ES5`.

Following the directions at the babel website's setup page kept giving me errors like yours. Then I figured out that the setup page is actually grossly out of date, but the correct commands for the current `babel cli` and `presets` are in their docs.

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli`

`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

These are taken directly from the docs and worked for me.

Of course, this will only work at the local level of whatever directory you're in when you run the commands. If you want to install babel globally you can use `-g`instead of `--save-dev`. They just have old commands that still work, but give older versions of babel, causing `peer dependency` issues.